# How to use a Bowser Javascript Library in index.html in script tags?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to use a Javascript Library in my AngularJS app, but i need this already in index.html before the angular app is initialized.

This is the library: https://github.com/lancedikson/bowser

And it is normally used like this:

```
const browser = Bowser.getParser(window.navigator.userAgent);

console.log(`The current browser name is "${browser.getBrowserName()}"`);
// The current browser name is "Internet Explorer"
```

The problem is, after i define the library in script tags:

```
<script src="lib/bower/..../bowser.js"></script>
```

Can i immediately use this in the next script tag within the index.html like this?

```
<script>
    const browser = Bowser.getParser(window.navigator.userAgent);
    ...
</script>
```

At the moment, Bowser is undefined.

Comment: Have you tried to use your Bowser object within a $(document).ready(function(){} block in the last script tag, in order to ensure the page is ready?

Comment: Unless it is designed to do so, the library will not nessesarily attached itself to a `Bowser` global object.  Without knowing exactly what `angular-bowser.js` is it is difficult to suggest a solution.

Comment: So, `angular-bowser` is available in the global scope as `window['angular-bowser']` if you include it in a script tag, however it is dependent on Angular to work.  I've checked the code of the `Bowser` library and it is built as a [UMD](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrarytarget) so it should then load itself as `window.Bowser` or just `Bowser` if included.  So, try adding a script tag for Bowser directly rather than angular-bowser.

Comment: https://github.com/lancedikson/bowser

Comment: it is actually the bowser itself.. not angular-bowser. sorry

Comment: @mggSoft there's no mention of jQuery anywhere in the question, so `$(document).ready` is not available here.

Comment: Have you checked that the script is actually loading in dev tools network?

Comment: try using `bowser` instead of `Bowser` - looks from their code as if it is not capitalised

Answer (score 2):

After checking the `Bowser` code it looks like it is not capitalised.  Further the bowser library file you are serving may not be intended to be used that way.  One solution is to serve a built version of bowser from a CDN:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bowser@2.5.3/es5.min.js"></script>
<script>
    const browser = bowser.getParser(window.navigator.userAgent);
    //...
</script>
```

Comment: in my case, the bowser is undefined because the script is somehow not compiled correctly.. when i start my app in production mode (with uglify etc.) it logs this error in terminal:  **'Unexpected token: name «Parser», expected: punc «;»',
  filename: '../../../build/.tmp/concat/js/vendor.js'**, and this comes from the script itself: `<script src="lib/bower/Bowser/src/bowser.js"></script>`

Comment: Well, just serving from the bower folder seems a little unusual to me, so the code you are serving may not be intended to be served in this way.  2 options: 1. do an explicit build of a small bundle to include or 2. include bowser from a separate source where it has already been built such as `https://unpkg.com/bowser@2.0.0-beta.3/es5.js`.

Comment: I've also changed the cdt to jsdelivr - probably a better choice for an answer, and a more up-to-date version of the lib.